# check valid value exist after first semicolon

Tags: sql, sql-server

may anyone please help me if possible

I am trying to check whether data in NONVALID column of @APPLICATION table contain remarks_1 value
which is present in @ATTRIBUTE table
**we can join the table with SKU as key column**

Table

```
DECLARE @ATTRIBUTE TABLE
(
SKU VARCHAR (50),
REMARKS_1 VARCHAR (50)
)

INSERT @ATTRIBUTE


SELECT 'AMRN205-740','P-215-40-18;' UNION ALL
SELECT 'NATN205-740','LT-275-65-20' UNION ALL
SELECT 'NATN205-740','XX-275-65-20' 



DECLARE @APPLICATION TABLE
(
SKU VARCHAR (50),
NONVALID VARCHAR (50)
)

 INSERT @APPLICATION
SELECT 'AMRN205-740','Plus Size; P-215-40-18; 87H' UNION ALL
SELECT 'BCTN205-740','Plus Size; P-215-40-18; 86H' UNION ALL
SELECT 'NATN205-740','Plus Size;  86H' UNION ALL
SELECT 'AMRN205-740', NULL union all
SELECT 'BCTN205-740','P-215-40-18; 86H' UNION ALL
SELECT ''BCTN205-740', ;86H'
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
'NATN205-740','Plus Size;  86H'
'BCTN205-740','P-215-40-18; 86H'-- plus size or semi-plus size before first   semicolon in a string is missing
   BCTN205-740', ;86H'-- plus size or semi-plus size before first semicolon in a string
```

AS AFTER FIRST SEMICOLON it does not contain either **LT-275-65-20** or **XX-275-65-20**

Thanks a lot

Comment: Let me introduce you to the `values` clause of the insert statement: `insert into @application values ('AMRN205-740','Plus Size; P-215-40-18; 87H'), ('BCTN205-740','Plus Size; P-215-40-18; 86H').…`

Comment: Hi, I've updated my answer

Comment: Hi, I've re-updated my answer, sorry for my fault

Comment: This row: SELECT 'BCTN205-740','P-215-40-18; 86H' why not included in expected output?

Comment: @JoeTaras: Sorry this should also be, included

Comment: Ok, so update your question and check my first query in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advice you to normalize better your tables:

I like prefer a table for SKU list named SKU as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE sku
(id int, name varchar(100))
```

id is a PK, name has the content of your field SKU (of your @attribute table)

```
CREATE TABLE attribute
(id int, 
 fk_sku int, 
 name varchar(100))
```

where you have attribute linked SKU

And finally,

```
CREATE TABLE application
(id int, 
fk_sku int,
fk_attribute int) <-- if you want to store this info or another I don't know
```

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM @APPLICATION app
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 'ATTRIBUTE'
    FROM @ATTRIBUTE att
    WHERE att.SKU = app.SKU
    AND PATINDEX('%' + att.REMARKS_1 + '%', app.NONVALID) > 0
)
and app.NONVALID IS NOT NULL
```

This query returns 'NATN205-740','Plus Size;  86H' and 'BCTN205-740','Plus Size; P-215-40-18; 86H'

If you want only 'NATN205-740','Plus Size;  86H' so:

```
SELECT *
FROM #APPLICATION app
WHERE EXISTS(
   SELECT 'ATTRIBUTE'
    FROM #ATTRIBUTE att
    WHERE att.SKU = app.SKU
)
AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 'ATTRIBUTE'
    FROM #ATTRIBUTE att
    WHERE att.SKU = app.SKU
    AND PATINDEX('%' + att.REMARKS_1 + '%', app.NONVALID) > 0
)
and app.NONVALID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Sorry, this is giving all the records instead of only the expected record

Comment: but the 2nd query is giving the NULL record instead of 'NATN205-740','Plus Size; 86H'

Comment: Ops, one moment, I check again ;)

Comment: Thanks Joe: if i want to also check a word "Plus size" before first ;  can i do it using Patindex. Please suggest.

Comment: Yes, write an example, because Plus size you have in application and not in attribute table

Comment: i have edited the question, and in expected output three records. the two records were there beacause I am trying to find those record also which does not contain plus size or semi-plus size before first semicolon in a string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109029/discussion-between-akhrot-and-joe-taras).